# Finding minimum value of $\tan A+\tan B$, given $A+B=30^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

> If $A>0$, $B>0$ and $A+B=30^\circ$, find the minimum value of $\tan A+\tan B$.

A similar question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1229870/if-ab-pi-3-then-what-will-maximum-value-of-tana-tanb). Many good answers are posted there. I understood that.

One particular answer by @Bill Kleinhans intrigued me as it was short and straightforward. But I didn't fully understand that answer. It uses Jensen's inequality, which I know, but don't know how to use that to get the answer here.

Not posting this as a comment there because Bill has been away close to three years now.

Comment: $f(x)=\tan x$ is convex on $(0,\frac {\pi} 6)$ since its second derivative $2\tan x \sec x$ is positive. Hence $f(\frac {A+B}2 ) \leq \frac {f(A)+f(B)} 2$.

Comment: Yes, @KaviRamaMurthy, I got upto that point. But don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: The minimum is $\tan (15^{0})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bill's idea may be this..

consider  $f(x)=\tan x$  $f''(x)=2\sec^2 x \tan x>0$ for $x\in (0,\pi/3)$

.By jensen $$f(x)+f(y)\le \frac{f(x)+f(y}{2}\Rightarrow \frac{\tan A+\tan B}{2}\ge {\tan(\frac{A+B}{2})}=\tan 15^o$$

Comment: Yes, I got upto that point but don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: @aarbee $A+B$ is given right? plug that

Comment: oh yes, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$\tan A+\tan B=\dfrac{\sin(A+B)}{\cos A\cos B}=\dfrac{2\sin(A+B)}{\cos(A-B)+\cos(A+B)} =\dfrac1{\cos(2A-30^\circ)+\dfrac{\sqrt3}2}$$

So, we need to maximize $\cos(2A-30^\circ)+\dfrac{\sqrt3}2$

Now  $-30^\circ<2A-30^\circ<30^\circ\implies\cos30^\circ<\cos(2A-30^\circ)\le1$